# I need to have a dynamic grid like masonry grid based on scores from json

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I want to display the json values into seperate grids . The height and width of the grid should be dynamically added based on the json values .
[IMAGE Link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2ZHL.png)

I have tried antd cards but each having the same grids . May be flexbox would be ideal I think . Let's say below is the json I receive . The grid for name ="Bill should be large than the next based on the score value

```
[{"NAME":"Holiday","Score":25}, 
{"NAME":"Bargain","Score":16}, 
{"NAME":"Frequent","Score":5}, 
{"NAME":"Weekend","Score":32}]
```

Comment: Can you share any code that you have already tried?

Comment: A visual representation of what this is supposed to look like would be useful but it doesn't *sound* like a grid....more like a bar chart.

Comment: added the visual representation in the post @Paulie_D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can technically do something in that direction with `grid`, although your `score` values seem a bit arbitrary and will therefore not result in a completely filled grid like in your visual. For that you'd have to decide what the column count on each row should be and then somehow "normalize" your scores so they fit into the columns...

```js
const data = [
  {"name": "Holiday", "score": 25}, 
  {"name": "Bargain", "score": 16}, 
  {"name": "Frequent", "score": 5}, 
  {"name": "Weekend", "score": 32},
];

document.querySelector('.grid').innerHTML = data.map(obj => {
  return `<div class="item" style="grid-column-end: span ${obj.score };"><span>${obj.name}</span></div>`;
}).join('\n');
```

```css
.grid {
  background: gold;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(41, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 8px;
}

.item {
  align-items: center;
  background: lightcoral;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 12px; font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

</div>
```

Comment: I think instead of grids I can go for any grid charts . This looks like pie chart but with square grids .